# Alternative for CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION on shared server with open_basedir ON

Tags: redirect, twitter, curl

I'm working on a script which pulls images from tweets with a certain hashtag. Normally this script is working just fine, as it's only has been implemented on dedicated servers where open_basedir and safe_mode were no problem to shut down.

However, right now, I'm trying to get this script to work for a client, which is hosting his website on a shared server, where open_basedir is ON. Result: Giving me an error when trying to fetch the redirected URL from the Twitter picture URL (several clients, like Twitpic, Yfrog).

This is the error I get:

> Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set in.....

Basicly, the script generates the Tweets in the database, where also the URL is stored. But when trying to create the image on the server, it gives me the result: 'hidden' as stated in the script below, as it cant find the MIME type from the direct URL. So, the URL stored in the database need to followed to the image path to pull the image and create it.

My question is, is there any way to rewrite the FOLLOWLOCATION part? I've searched for about 3 hours for a solution, but can't seem to implement it right...

Hopefully anyone can help me

The script:

```
<?php
# Database gegevens inladen
include('config.php');

$query = mysql_query("select * from tweets where loaded=0 and hidden=0 order by id asc limit ".$maximgload);
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
while($db = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $db->url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if(!empty($buffer)){
        # Afbeelding opslaan
        $fp = fopen($imgdir.'/'.$db->id.'.temp', 'x');
        fwrite($fp, $buffer);
        fclose($fp);


        if(!function_exists('mime_content_type')) {

            function mime_content_type($filename) {

                    $mime_types = array(

                        // images
                        'png' => 'image/png',
                        'jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
                        'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
                        'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
                    );

                $ext = strtolower(array_pop(explode('.',$filename)));
                if (array_key_exists($ext, $mime_types)) {
                    return $mime_types[$ext];
                }
                elseif (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
                    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
                    $mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
                    finfo_close($finfo);
                    return $mimetype;
                }
                else {
                    return 'application/octet-stream';
                }
            }
        }

        # Bestand omzetten naar juiste formaat
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($imgdir.'/'.$db->id.'.temp');
        # Jpg
        if($mimetype == 'image/jpeg'){
            rename($imgdir.'/'.$db->id.'.temp',$imgdir.'/'.$db->id.'.jpg');
        }
        # Png
        elseif($mimetype == 'image/png'){
            rename($imgdir.'/'.$db->id.'.temp',$imgdir.'/'.$db->id.'.png');
        }
        # Ander (onbekend) formaat? weg er mee!
        else{
            @unlink($imgdir.'/'.$db->id.'.temp');
            @mysql_query("update tweets set hidden='1' where id='".$db->id."'");
            $result = 'file '.$db->id.' onbekend';
            break;
        }

        # Thumbnail maken
        $source_image = imagecreatefromstring($buffer);
        $source_width = imagesx($source_image); 
        $source_height = imagesy($source_image); 
        $source_ratio = $source_width / $source_height; 
        $destination_ratio = $thumbwidth / $thumbheight;
        // landscape
        if($source_ratio > $destination_ratio){ 
            $temp_width = (int)($source_height * $destination_ratio); 
            $temp_height = $source_height; 
            $source_x = (int)(($source_width - $temp_width) / 2); 
            $source_y = 0; 
        }
        // portrait
        else { 
            $temp_width = $source_width; 
            $temp_height = (int)($source_width * $destination_ratio); 
            $source_x = 0; 
            $source_y = (int)(($source_height - $temp_height) / 2); 
        } 
        $destination_x = 0; 
        $destination_y = 0; 
        $source_width = $temp_width; 
        $source_height = $temp_height; 
        $new_destination_width = $thumbwidth; 
        $new_destination_height = $thumbheight;

        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbwidth,$thumbheight);
        imagecopyresampled($thumb,$source_image,$destination_x,$destination_y,$source_x,$source_y,$new_destination_width,$new_destination_height,$source_width,$source_height);
        # Thumbnail opslaan
        if($mimetype == 'image/jpeg'){
            imagejpeg($thumb,$imgdir.'/'.$db->id.'_thumb.jpg');
        }
        else{
            imagepng($thumb,$imgdir.'/'.$db->id.'_thumb.png');
        }

        # Bijwerken in database
        mysql_query("update tweets set loaded='1', mime='".$mimetype."' where id='".$db->id."'");
        $result = 'afb '.$db->id.' gemaakt';
    }
    # Kan url niet openen? Dan uit database gooien
    else{
        mysql_query("update tweets set hidden='1' where id='".$db->id."'");
        $result = 'afb '.$db->id.' hidden';
    }
}
}
else{
$result = 'done';
}
echo '<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2">
<title>'.$result.'</title>
</head>
</html>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this one function, it use recurrence to simulate followlocation

```
/**
 * @param cURL  $ch                     - uchwyt do cURL
 * @param int   $redirects              - przekierowania
 * @param bool  $curlopt_returntransfer - CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER
 * @param int   $curlopt_maxredirs      - CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS
 * @param bool  $curlopt_header         - CURLOPT_HEADER
 * @return mixed
 */
function curl_redirect_exec($ch, &$redirects, $curlopt_returntransfer = false, $curlopt_maxredirs = 10, $curlopt_header = false) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $exceeded_max_redirects = $curlopt_maxredirs > $redirects;
    $exist_more_redirects = false;
    if ($http_code == 301 || $http_code == 302) {
        if ($exceeded_max_redirects) {
            list($header) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data, 2);
            $matches = array();
            preg_match('/(Location:|URI:)(.*?)\n/', $header, $matches);
            $url = trim(array_pop($matches));
            $url_parsed = parse_url($url);
            if (isset($url_parsed)) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                $redirects++;
                return curl_redirect_exec($ch, $redirects, $curlopt_returntransfer, $curlopt_maxredirs, $curlopt_header);
            }
        }
        else {
            $exist_more_redirects = true;
        }
    }
    if ($data !== false) {
        if (!$curlopt_header)
            list(,$data) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data, 2);
        if ($exist_more_redirects) return false;
        if ($curlopt_returntransfer) {
            return $data;
        }
        else {
            echo $data;
            if (curl_errno($ch) === 0) return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://some-website.com");
$redirects = 0;
curl_redirect_exec($ch, $redirects);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Code taken from: http://antczak.org/2009/12/curl-rozwiazanie-problemu-z-curlopt_followlocation/